# I want to make my own coloring for the code in a textbox. How do I not change the whole textbox one color?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

//using an array isn't helping 
document.getElementById("textarea")[0].style.color = 'red';

Comment: You cannot style individual characters in a `<textarea>` or text `<input>` without doing some elaborate CSS tricks to overlay separate `<span>` tags. It's possible, but it would be a lot of work (especially for a `<textarea>`) and I'd question whether it would be worth it.

Comment: You may want to use a content editable  `div` instead.